# Saving a ToggleButton state

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not really familiar with MVVM so I'm not sure where I should start If the solution is there but what I've done so far is the following (using code behind):

I basically have a toggle button, If you check it, It will write something in the registry and If you uncheck it, It will remove the same thing from registry. I simply added Checked and Unchecked events.

The problem here is that I want to save the state of the ToggleButton (Whether It was checked or unchecked). I was able to do this on the form load by comparing the registry and then turning isChecked to true or false but the problem is that If I turn isChecked to true, It will trigger the 'Checked' event and basically write the same thing on registry again.

```
 private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        if (rk.GetValue("Z") == null)
        {
            Toggle.IsChecked = false;

        }
        else
        {
            Toggle.IsChecked = true;
        }

    }
    private void Toggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        RegistryKey rkRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);


        rkRegistryKey.SetValue("Z", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);



    }
    private void Toggle_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        RegistryKey rkRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        rkRegistryKey.DeleteValue("Z", false);


    }
```

Comment: Psst, do not use MVVM :) unless you're really going to reuse the View-Model through different projects!

Comment: Really? that's not what I hear everyone saying

Comment: There are lots of debates on that matter.. check this [Advantages and disadvantages of M-V-VM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johngossman/2006/03/04/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-m-v-vm/)

Comment: 99% of wpf development is done using MVVM. It's the de facto standard. For good reasons.  If all you're doing is writing a trivial application and that's all you ever want to do then it doesn't matter and you can do what you want. If you intend ever doing wpf development commercially then learn MVVM and be prepared to answer MVVM questions at interview.  If you want to persist state between runs and you have no database then you can just serialise objects to disk. Which is how this works: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Dynamic-Fonts-ad3741ca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean variable to temporarily "suspend" the event handlers:

```
private bool _handleEvents;
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

    _handleEvents = false;
    if (rk.GetValue("Z") == null)
    {
        Toggle.IsChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Toggle.IsChecked = true;
    }
    _handleEvents = true;

}
private void Toggle_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_handleEvents)
        return;

    RegistryKey rkRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);


    rkRegistryKey.SetValue("Z", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
}

private void Toggle_UnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_handleEvents)
        return;

    RegistryKey rkRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

    rkRegistryKey.DeleteValue("Z", false);
}
```